# Locationmatch not working

Tags: apache-2.4, proxypass

I have these 2 LocationMatch directives

```
<LocationMatch "^.*system/app_dev\.php(.*)$">
            ProxyPass fcgi://127.0.0.1:9998/var/www/example.com/trunk/system/web/app_dev.php
</LocationMatch>
<LocationMatch "^.*system(.*)$">
            ProxyPass fcgi://127.0.0.1:9998/var/www/example.com/trunk/system/web/app.php
</LocationMatch>
```

I expect

```
http://example.com/system/app_dev.php/files/abc
```

to be matched by the first rule

```
http://example.com/system/files/abc
```

by the second rule.

However in my case both are matched by the 2nd rule.

This is on Apache 2.4

Answer (score 1):

Location and LocationMatch should be defined, **less specific first**. So the second is being matched because it should have been defined first and it is overriding what you defined in the first one.

Comment: Reference: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#overlapping-webspace

Answer (score 0):

try escaping the slash?

```
<LocationMatch "^.*system\/app_dev\.php(.*)$">
```